# WSO2 MI How to create an Insert or Update PUT resource?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I want to create a PUT resource in WSO2 Micro Integrator, so I can either insert or update event records, but it's not even accepting my http request. Could you help me configure this correctly?

What I was expecting was that when I'd call something like this, it would insert in batch into the database.

```bash
curl --location --request PUT 'http://wso2-mi.mkwtf.com/services/APIDataService/eventRecord?calendar_date=2022-12-01' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
--data-raw '
    <event_record_list>
        <event_record>
            <event_type>1000124</event_type>
            <event_count>217140</event_count>
        </event_record>
        <event_record>
            <event_type>1000127</event_type>
            <event_count>1567</event_count>
        <event_record>
        </event_record>
            <event_type>1000129</event_type>
            <event_count>31</event_count>
        </event_record>
    </event_record_list>'
```

But in reality it responds with this:

```xml
<axis2ns52:DataServiceFault xmlns:axis2ns52="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <axis2ns52:current_params>{event_type=1000124, event_count=217140}</axis2ns52:current_params>
    <axis2ns52:source_data_service>
        <axis2ns52:data_service_name>APIDataService</axis2ns52:data_service_name>
        <axis2ns52:description></axis2ns52:description>
        <axis2ns52:location>/home/wso2/qa/wso2mi/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1671624403635APICompositeExporter_1.0.0.car/APIDataService_1.0.0/APIDataService-1.0.0.dbs</axis2ns52:location>
        <axis2ns52:default_namespace>http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice</axis2ns52:default_namespace>
    </axis2ns52:source_data_service>
    <axis2ns52:ds_code>INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR</axis2ns52:ds_code>
    <axis2ns52:current_request_name>_puteventrecord</axis2ns52:current_request_name>
</axis2ns52:DataServiceFault>
```

However, when I make this request, I'm able to make the request, and it returns me with 202, but I'm only able to insert or update one row at a time.

```bash
curl --location --request PUT 'http://wso2-mi.mkwtf.com/services/APIDataService/eventRecord?calendar_date=2022-12-01&event_type=1000124&event_count=217140' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'calendar_date=2022-12-01' \
--data-urlencode 'event_type=1000124' \
--data-urlencode 'event_count=217140'
```

Here is the Data Service definition:

```xml
<data name="APIDataService" serviceNamespace="" serviceGroup="" transports="http https local">
    <description />
    
    <config id="postgresDataService">
        <property name="carbon_datasource_name">APIPostgres</property>
    </config>
    
    <query id="eventRecord" useConfig="postgresDataService">
        <sql>
            INSERT INTO event_record(calendar_date, event_type, event_count)
            VALUES (:calendar_date, :event_type, :event_count)
            ON CONFLICT (calendar_date, event_type)
            DO UPDATE SET event_count = EXCLUDED.event_count
        </sql>
        
        <param name="calendar_date" sqlType="date"    />
        <param name="event_type"    sqlType="integer" />
        <param name="event_count"   sqlType="integer" />
        
        <properties>
          <property name="forceJDBCBatchRequests">true</property>
        </properties>
    </query>
    <resource method="PUT" path="eventRecord">
        <call-query href="eventRecord">
            <with-param name="calendar_date" query-param="calendar_date" />
            <with-param name="event_type"    query-param="event_type"    />
            <with-param name="event_count"   query-param="event_count"   />
        </call-query>
    </resource>

</data>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @sanoJ Just added the requests I'm doing, thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 0):

Due to a limitation of MI[1], you cannot use both the request body and URL params to call a dataservice. When the content type is set in the request it tries to dispatch to the data service operation based on the request body and ignores the URL params. As a result, you will observe the `INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR` error. Therefore you will need to pass all the required parameters of the `eventRecord` operation in your request body. Can you try to send a request as follows,

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://wso2-mi.mkwtf.com/services/APIDataService/eventRecord' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
--data-raw '
    <event_record_list>
        <event_record>
            <calendar_date>2022-12-01</calendar_date>
            <event_type>1000124</event_type>
            <event_count>217140</event_count>
        </event_record>
        <event_record>
            <calendar_date>2022-12-01</calendar_date>
            <event_type>1000127</event_type>
            <event_count>1567</event_count>
        <event_record>
        </event_record>
            <calendar_date>2022-12-01</calendar_date>
            <event_type>1000129</event_type>
            <event_count>31</event_count>
        </event_record>
    </event_record_list>'
```

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2811

Comment: I made that request ( here: https://pastebin.com/qbyBpwhX ) and got a similar response to the one I got before ( here: https://pastebin.com/rJNLuCmx )

Comment: @MkWTF What is the MI version? I tested this in MI 4.1.0 and it was working

Comment: That's the version as well, here is the response from the https://wso2-apim.mkwtf.com:9443/services/Version endpoint: `<ns:getVersionResponse xmlns:ns="http://version.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
<return>WSO2 API Manager-4.1.0</return>
</ns:getVersionResponse>`

Comment: In the initial request and dataservice you shared in the question is `APIDataService` Did you update the dataservice to `ClimberAPIDataService`? In the shared pastebin you have called something like `ClimberAPIDataService`

Comment: Sorry, no I didn't update the DataService, assume it's still the APIDataService pls